# Django raising Type Error "profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'"

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I've been working with Django for a short while and today I ran into a problem that for the life of me I can't figure out. I'm trying to load the user's profile which they themselves have saved on a previous step, however when I try to open the page where the profile should be so they can see it and edit it I am getting the error I mentioned.

Here are my views.py

```
@verified_email_required()
def home(request):
    usuario = Perfil.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = ({"usuario": usuario})
    return render(request, "explore/inicioapp.html", context)

@verified_email_required()
def profile(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Perfil, id=id)
    form = ProfileForm(instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            perfil = form.save(commit=False)
            perfil.user = request.user
            perfil.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/profile/")
    context = ({"form", form}, {"datos": instance})
    return render(request, "explore/profile.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    Sexo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CP = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Pais = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Telefono = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Celular = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    PaisPasaporte = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    NumeroPasaporte = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    VigenciaPasaporte = models.DateField(max_length=100)
    ContactoEmergencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    TelefonoEmergencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CorreoEmergencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Alergias = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        exclude = ["user"]
        widgets = {
            'Sexo': Select(choices=opciones_sexo, attrs={'class': 'selectpicker'}),
            'VigenciaPasaporte': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'})
        }
        labels = {
            'Sexo': _("Gender"),
            'Direccion': _("Address"),
            'CP': _("Zip code"),
            'Ciudad': _("City"),
            'Estado': _("State"),
            'Pais': _("Country"),
            'Telefono': _("Phone"),
            'Celular': _("Cellphone"),
            'PaisPasaporte': _("Passport emission country"),
            'NumeroPasaporte': _("Passport number"),
            'VigenciaPasaporte': _("Passport expiration date"),
            'ContactoEmergencia': _("Emergency contact person"),
            'TelefonoEmergencia': _("Emergency contact phone"),
            'CorreoEmergencia': _("Emergency contact email")
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("label_suffix", "")
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProfileForm, self).clean()
        sexoseleccionado = cleaned_data.get("Sexo")
        if sexoseleccionado == "none":
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must select a gender to continue.")
        return cleaned_data
```

url

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user>\d+)$', views.profile, name="profile"),
```

And finally the HTML link

```
<a class="btn btn-menu" href="{% url "explore:profile" Perfil.id %}">{% trans "My Profile" %}</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your url pattern is passing an argument user, but your view method is defining the argument as id.

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user>\d+)$', views.profile, name="profile"),
                   ^^^^
```

Your view method, however:

```
@verified_email_required()
def profile(request, id):
                     ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a name issue. In the URL for profile you are capturing a "user" variable. But the view itself is expecting an "id" argument. Make these consistent.